# Rails is caching my pdfs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, prawn

I have a rails 4 app running on Heroku that uses Prawn to generate pdf views.

I have changed my view file and nevertheless I keep getting the original file.

I don't know whether this is a rails issue, a heroku issue or a prawn issue...

Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: Yes, I did restart it... changed the code multiple times, but still no success. But it's a browser thing, just need to figure out how to get chrome not to use the cached version....